# Server-Client malfunction in Android (socket is not bound/socket is already in use)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, serial-port

Hayho,

well my problem is a little tricky to me to explain. I try to connect my android tablet (4.0.3) to a RS-232 converter. That already works, but only oneway. If i try to send anything, it is sended. I cannot receive any answers, but this is neccessary. I get this

```
    Logcat Errors: Either Socket is not bound, or EADRESS already in use.
```

I tried multiple ways,  but none worked as i need it.

**My target:** Sending AND receiving Bytes whenever they are sent.

**My Architecture:** MainActivity -> calls 2 Asynctasks
1. network, 2. ConcurrentServer
network has to send my commands via DataOutputStream. Allright here.
ConcurrentServer has to receive incoming Data with DataInputStream, give it to a method in ConcurrentServer class. This method should send an answerbyte.

My ConcurrentServer doesn't receive, nor does the method send anything...

I hope you can help me with that.

**Code:**

```
package com.example.wettkampftimerbt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConcurrentServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private final String LFDNR1 = "lfdnr1";
    private final String LFDNR2 = "lfdnr2";
    private final String LFDNR3 = "lfdnr3";
    private final String LFDNR4 = "lfdnr4";
    private final String LFDNR5 = "lfdnr5";
    private final String LFDNR6 = "lfdnr6";
    private final String LFDNR7 = "lfdnr7";
    private final String LFDNR8 = "lfdnr8", PREFS_NAME = "prefs",
            COMMAND = "command", LANE = "lane", DINYMIN ="dinymin", DINYSEK="dinysek";

    int w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, diny1, diny2, diny3, diny4, diny5,
            diny6, diny7, diny8, dinymin, dinysek;
    Context context;
    ServerSocket sock;
    Socket ss;



        protected Void doInBackground (Void... arg0) {
            System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_doInBackgorund");
            Log.e("SERVER", "CON");
        try {
            sock = new ServerSocket(2010);
            ss = sock.accept();
            sock.setReuseAddress(true);
            sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2010));

            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
            ss = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 2011);
            sock.setSoTimeout(1000);
            for (;;) {
                boolean stopData = true;    
                BufferedReader din = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));


                //DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(
                    //  ss.getInputStream());
                while (stopData) {
                // Einlesen
                diny1 = (din).read();// 03
                diny2 = (din).read();// Empfänger(90...97)
                diny3 = (din).read();// Sender(80)
                diny4 = (din).read();// lfdnr
                diny5 = (din).read();// Kommando(Start, Stop...)
                if (diny5==79){
                dinymin = (din).read();//Minuten
                dinysek = (din).read();//Sekunden
                }
                diny6 = (din).read();// Prüfsumme
                diny7 = (din).read();// 05
                din.close();
                //ss.close();
                //sock.close();
                System.out
                        .println("diny: " + diny1 + " " + diny2 + " " + diny3
                                + " " + diny4 + " " + diny5 + " " + diny6 + " "
                                + diny7);
                Log.e("Reccom", "RECCOM");
                reccom();


                stopData=false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO error" + e);}
        return null;
        }



    public int getLFDNR1(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr1");
        w1 = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(LFDNR1, 00);
        //w1 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR1);
        return w1;
    }

    public String getLFDNR2(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr2");
        w2 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR2);
        return LFDNR2;
    }

    public String getLFDNR3(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr3");
        w3 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR3);
        return LFDNR3;
    }

    public String getLFDNR4(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr4");
        w4 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR4);
        return LFDNR4;
    }

    public String getLFDNR5(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr5");
        w5 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR5);
        return LFDNR5;
    }

    public String getLFDNR6(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr6");
        w6 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR6);
        return LFDNR6;
    }

    public String getLFDNR7(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr7");
        w7 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR7);
        return LFDNR7;
    }

    public String getLFDNR8(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_getlfdnr8");
        w8 = Integer.valueOf(LFDNR8);
        return LFDNR8;
    }
    private void reccom() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_reccom");
        if (diny1 == 3 && diny7 == 5) {
            answer();
        } else {
        }

        switch (diny2) {
        case (144): // 144=90=Bahn1
            c144(context);
            break;
        case (145): // 145=91=Bahn2
            c145(context);
            break;
        case (146): // 146=92=Bahn3
            c146(context);
            break;
        case (147): // 147=93=Bahn4
            c147(context);
            break;
        case (148): // 148=94=Bahn5
            c148(context);
            break;
        case (149): // 149=95=Bahn6
            c149(context);
            break;
        case (150): // 150=96=Bahn7
            c150(context);
            break;
        case (151): // 151=97=Bahn8
            c151(context);
            break;
        }

    }

    private void answer() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_answer");
    Socket sock ;
    int w0=0,w5=32;
         SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.100", 2011);  
         sock = new Socket();  
         int timeout = 1000;   // 1000 millis = 1 second  
         sock.connect(sockaddr, timeout); 
        boolean stopData = true;
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        while (stopData) {
            dos.writeByte(w0);
            dos.writeByte(diny1);
            dos.writeByte(diny3);
            dos.writeByte(diny2);
            dos.writeByte(diny4);
            dos.writeByte(w5);
            dos.writeByte(diny6);
            dos.writeByte(diny7);
            dos.flush();
            //dos.close();
            stopData = false;}

    }

    private void c151(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c151");
        getLFDNR8(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {

                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "151").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr8 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c150(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c150");
        getLFDNR7(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "150").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr7 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c149(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c149");
        getLFDNR6(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "149").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr6 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c148(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c148");
        getLFDNR5(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "148").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr5 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c147(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c147");
        getLFDNR4(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "147").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr4 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c146(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c146");
        getLFDNR3(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "146").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr3 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c145(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c145");
        getLFDNR2(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "145").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("lfdnr2 passt nicht");
        }
    }

    private void c144(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_c144");
        final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
        final String COMMAND = "command";
        final String LANE = "lane", DINYMIN ="dinymin", DINYSEK="dinysek";
        getLFDNR1(context);
        if (w1 == diny4||(w1-1)==diny4)
            switch (diny5) {
            case (00):
            case (79): {
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(LANE, "144").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putString(COMMAND, "79").commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYMIN, Integer.valueOf(dinymin).toString()).commit();
                context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString(DINYSEK, Integer.valueOf(dinysek).toString()).commit();
            }
                break;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println(w1+ "+"+ diny4);
            System.out.println("lfdnr1 passt nicht");
        }

    }

    public ConcurrentServer(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ConcurrentServer_Context");
        this.context = context;

    }



}
```

If you think, you should need the network-code, too, please tell it to me. 
BTW: this is my code NOW, after experimenting and trying a lot of things. So if anything is doubled, this is the reason. In Cause of I am a newbie on Android it may happens to me.

Thanks.

EDIT:

This link, given by Class Stacker is very good. It`s in detailed and precise. For anyone who's having trouble, check this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html

Thanks one more time Class Stacker!

Comment: You get what exception at what line of code? This code is fairly nonsensical. I strongly recommend you study the Custom Networking trail in the Java Tutorial before proceeding any further.

Comment: cant tell you, i get both of them, depending on whatever...one time the one and another time the second...

Comment: @Ektion That doesn't answer my question. Which line of code? If you get two exceptions, which *lines?*

Comment: wait,... its an exception, not an error in the similar way... i let it print oout by System.out.println... sry for mistelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please note that, depending on your Android version, AsyncTasks are not executed in parallel, unless you explicitly specify the executor for that.
2. I guess you'll have to actively connect to the converter device. If so, you don't have a server socket; it's really a client socket.
3. I have no idea why you create so many sockets along the way; a socket is a bi-directional communication channel.
4. *If* you really need a server socket, you wait vor incoming connections, which you `accept()`, and `accept()` will give you your client-specific socket.

Hote this helps; if not, you need to update your questions with information about the device you're connecting to, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: hmmm thx so far... you tell me, i open with             sock = new ServerSocket(2010);
            ss = sock.accept();
            sock.setReuseAddress(true);
            sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2010)); a bidirectional connection? how do i read incoming bytes? I can decide, if the converter is  a server or a client, so this doesnt matter. My Device is the USR-TCP232E

Comment: @Ekonion You bind the socket only once to a local address; it's enough to do it in the constructor. Also, `setReuseAddress()` does not what you think it does; no need to set it PLUS the way you set it won't work either. The main question is: Is your communication asynchronous, in other words, can both ends (converter and your app) initiate communication? If _yes_, then you will have to either use `java.nio` and wait for the first event that happens, or hope the best. In worst case, you'll need a complex state machine. So what kind of data will be transferred?

Comment: so i can delete my 'reuse' and change my socket-placement to the constructor of my class, yes? Fine. ^^ To the comunication: My app can send the commands, but it does not receive the commands, the converter sends. I know they are sent. The data i send are just bytes like 03, 20, or 90. Integer written out as Byte. See source under answer. There's this operation.

Comment: @Ekonion Create socket in constructor? No way. Don't do that. Constructor of which class? It _might_ work but better avoid it. Also, _do not_ construct BufferedThingies on demand; you will lose data! Construct them di4rectly after `accept()`.

Comment: But you said it oo in your first sentence or misunderstood I? But i need e bufferedReader, because every command has to be answered and worked out, or is there any other way to do this? My app blocks, if a command is working, isnt it? So i need a buffer that, even if two commands are sent almost the same time, both are executed. And one important point: Im working with android since 2 months. I still have problems with the vocabulary of Android.. I do not exactly know what a constructor is. Is it the first, what is done when class is created, called?

Comment: @Ekonion A constructor is _nothing_ that is Android specific. Also, your understanding of what a BufferedReader is good for is wrong, plus how you should design your iomplementation to support "two commands at almost the same time". I suggest you take the time to read through Java socket and I/O tutorials if you want your app to work.

Comment: I already read lots of stuff specific to this, but it seems i dont get it. Everything i tried went wrong. I am on this problem for 2 weeks now, everyday working 8 hours and trying more and more. I am a little dispared now.

Comment: @Ekonion That's not much if you're new to Java, Android _and_ sockets. Depending on your background, it could take you some months to achieve a more or less robust implementation. Question is, how do you proceed. Are you getting paid for this?

Comment: yes, and my boss is a little angry, i cannot show any successes there.

Comment: @Ekonion Somewhat understandable. -- Your TCP/IP<->RS232 thingy is going to be transparent afrter the initialization; which device are you really going to talk to and what are its requirements?

Comment: I talk through this RS232 to a self-developed machine of my companys technics. It needs a commandline of Hexadezimal bytes. I send them decimal, because it receives them Hexadecimal automatically. Does it help you?

Comment: As I said, the required complexity of your solution depends on the specification of the data protocol between your app and your company's device, of which I have no impression. I wasted my time looking at the spec of the converter, though. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I can't be so hard, just to build a server-client activity which receives whenever anything is send :( My best solution till now was that i got the sent commands, but i had to reconnect manually after every. But this isn't THE solution... So, independent of what my machine needs, can you give me a working client-server activity with AsyncTask? I'll try to modify that to my need.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, AsyncTask is _not_ the right way to do it. Create HanlderThread or Thread for that. Mybe you can lice with a simple send - receive scheme, I don't know. Also, make this a client socket, not a server socket (just my gut feeling). And starting from there, why don't you simply follow a regular Java socket tutorial, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) or [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html). And you post your results to the main thread via Handler.post().

Comment: well thx so far, i'll work through and try my best ^^ already learned a bit. So What I am doing now: Deleting my Async, try to implement a Thread and changing my server socket to a client socket... Thx for your time ^^.

Comment: @Ekonion Okay that was too much. I spent all this time and you "reward" me by not even _upvoting_ my help. I can't believe it.

Comment: WTF? i checked the hook oo... it was because i thought u can set multiple hooks ^.^ sry :D and upvoting is not possible.. too low rep :D

Comment: @Ekonion Oh ok thx :) The not-really matlab code is going to help you more than the Java socket tutorials I provided?

Comment: For sure not, but idk, if i need an example of one specific thing,e.g. the writing part. I had it often, that example codes didnt work for me. If i have two sources of known function you can compare these and it may be better to understand. AND i asked for a working source in our discussion and he gave me, so i wanted to hook both of you, NOW i know this is not possible ^^ additionally you helped me more precise, thats the reason you get the hook.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Done it, with the knowing, a socket is bidirectional and can read AND write i got it now, i just shifted 2 seperate classes into each other and voilá it works ^^ no doublebound sockets left. Thanks Class Stacker. FOr help with the same or an even issue have a look at the link above.

Comment: Glad to read! Wasn't notified of this answer; just came across it.